# Accessing zabbix API with node-fetch

Tags: node.js, zabbix, node-fetch, zabbix-api

I am trying to access Zabbix API from a Node.js app with the following code:

```js
fetch(
  "http://localhost:8080/api_jsonrpc.php",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"apiinfo.version","params":[],"id":1},
  }
)
  .then((data) => {
    return data.json();
  })
  .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data)
  })
```

But I get an error:

```json
{
   jsonrpc: '2.0'
   error:{
      code:-32700,
      message: 'Parse error',
      data: 'Invalid JSON. An error occurred on the server while parsing the JSON text.'
   },
   id:null
}
```

However, when I use the following curl request, the API returns the correct value:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"apiinfo.version","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8080/api_jsonrpc.php
```

It is probably some problem with my fetch request but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` argument seems wrong - it should be `body, and should be a string (or a few other options that aren't relevant here), not an object:

```js
fetch(
  "http://localhost:8080/api_jsonrpc.php",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"apiinfo.version","params":[],"id":1}' // Here!
  }
)
// The .then part was snipped for brevity's sake
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns the same error

Comment: @Grimalkin I wasn't paying enough attention - it should be `body`, not `data`

Comment: Now it works thank you! I actually spoted this mistake just a second ago while using [this](https://www.scrapingbee.com/curl-converter/javascript-fetch/) great tool